# Javascript Functions for Form are not Displaying with textContent

Tags: javascript, function, getelementbyid

In my current code, I have a form that takes in 4 input quantities. Once inputted, the user will click the purchase button and the total counts of: total items, subtotal, sales tax, total and final discount amount will display based on what the user previously inputted.

My current issue is that nothing seems to print. Not even my error checking print. 
So far all that displays is the current "0" values for each value for the shopping cart.

Please help me understand where my issues lie. 
I have some concern that the getElementsByClassId may be causing my problem too for the class inside the () for it. Not completely sure where to start.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- Set the viewport so this responsive site displays correctly on mobile devices -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Page title </title>
<!-- Include bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Include jQuery library -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  thead { background-color: #333; color: #fff; font-weight: bold;  }
  .items, #nitems, #subtotal, #tax, #total, #final {text-align: right; width: 100px; }
  #checkout { margin-bottom: 45px; width: 200px; height: 50px; font-weight: bold; }
  #errors { padding-bottom: 200px; clear: both; font-weight: bold; clear: both; font-size: 20px;
  color: blue;
 }
</style>

</head>
<body class='container'>
<form name="testForm">
  <div class='row'>
  <div class='col-md-8'>
   <h2>Sam's Online Shop</h2>

   <h3>15% discount on all online sales </h3>

   <h3>Our World Famous Chocolates Now Available Online </h3>
     <table class='table'>
     <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Product</th><th>Unit cost</th><th>Quantity</th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td id="ch-1-label">Milk Chocolate</td>
      <td id="ch-1-cost">7.48</td>
      <td><input size=3 name="milkchoc" id="ch-1-qnt" class="form-control items" value="0"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td id="ch-2-label">Assorted Fine Chocolates</td>
      <td id="ch-2-cost">9.98</td>
      <td><input size=3 name="foil" id="ch-2-qnt" class="form-control items" value="0"></td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
      <td id="ch-3-label">Assorted Milk & Dark Chocolates</td>
      <td id="ch-3-cost">12.98</td>
      <td><input size=3 name="dc" id="ch-3-qnt" class="form-control items" value="0"></td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
      <td id="ch-4-label">Assorted Dessert Truffles</td>
      <td id="ch-4-cost">15.98</td>
      <td><input size=3 name="dt" id="ch-4-qnt" class="form-control items" value="0"></td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class='row'>
   <div class='col-md-4'>

  <h3>Shopping Cart </h3>
  <table class='table'>
    <tr>
      <td>Total Items</td>
      <td><span  id="nitems" >0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Subtotal</td>
      <td><span  id="subtotal" >0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5% Sales tax</td>
      <td><span id="tax" >0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td><span id="total" >0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Final amount (with 15% discount)</td>
      <td><span id="final"  >0</td>
    </tr>
   </table>



 <p><input type="button" value="Purchase" id="checkout" class="form-control btn btn-primary" /></p>
 <p><span id='errors'></span></p>
 </div>
 </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE AT BOTTOM OF HTML CODE

```
 <script>
 // Include Javascript code here 

 document.getElementById('Purchase').onclick = function() {

var milk = document.getElementById('ch-1-qnt').value;
var fine = document.getElementById('ch-2-qnt').value;
var both = document.getElementById('ch-3-qnt').value;
var truff = document.getElementById('ch-4-qnt').value;
//Check for errors
var errors = checkErrors();
//Display the errors
if (errors.length > 0)
    //displayErrors(errors);
    checkErrors();
}
else {
    // Display function for total count of items purchased
    displayitems();
    // Return subTotal function that totals the initial cost for all
    var subTotal = Sub(milk, fine, both, truff);
    document.getElementByID('subtotal').textContent = subTotal;
    //Return Tax function totals
    var salesTax = Tax(subTotal);
    document.getElementById('tax').textContent = salesTax;
    // Return the total cost for Subtotal cost and salesTax cost
    var Total = displayTotal(subTotal, salesTax);
    document.getElementById('total').textContent = Total;
    // Display discount pricing
    var DiscountTotal = Total * .15;
    document.getElementById('final').textContent = DiscountTotal;
}

//Returns an array of error messages
function checkErrors() {
var list = [];

for (var j = 1; j<4; j++){

if (document.getElementById('ch-' + j + '-qnt')).value <0 ) {
    document.getElementById('errors').innerHTML = list;
    }   
}

}

// Display total item counts
function displayItems() {
var total = 0;
var input = document.getElementsByClassId('form-control items');
for (var i=0; i<input.length; i++){
    total += parseFloat(input[i].value);
}
document.getElementById('nitems').textContent = total;  
}

//Function to return the subtotal for all 4 inputs
function Sub(milk, fine, both, truff) {
var total1, total2, total3, total4 = 0;
var Final = 0;
var costMilk = 7.48;
var costFine = 9.98;
var costBoth = 12.98;
var costTruff = 15.98;

total1 = costMilk * milk;
total2 = costFine *fine;
total3 = costBoth * both;
total4 = costTruff * truff;

Final = total1 + total2 + total3 + total4;
return Final;
}

// Returns tax total
function Tax(subTotal) {

subTotal = Sub(milk, fine, both, truff);
var Tax = subTotal * .05;

return Tax;
}

function displayTotal(Tax, Sub){

return Tax * Sub;

}

};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's no such function as `getElementsByClassId`. It's `getElementsByClassName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many errors on your scripts, the list of errors are

- `document.getElementById('Purchase').onclick // using wrong id Purchase but checkout`
- `if (errors.length > 0) //forgot closing brace {, but if (errors.length > 0){`
- `displayitems(); //wrong function calling, but displayItems()`
- `document.getElementsByClassId('form-control items'); //should be document.getElementsByClassName`
- `(document.getElementById('ch-' + j + '-qnt').value) <0 ) //extra parenthesis ) after value, but (document.getElementById('ch-' + j + '-qnt').value <0 )`

```js
document.getElementById('checkout').onclick = function() {

var milk = document.getElementById('ch-1-qnt').value;
var fine = document.getElementById('ch-2-qnt').value;
var both = document.getElementById('ch-3-qnt').value;
var truff = document.getElementById('ch-4-qnt').value;
//Check for errors
var errors = checkErrors();
//Display the errors
if (errors.length > 0) {
    //displayErrors(errors);
    checkErrors();
}else {
    // Display function for total count of items purchased
    displayItems();
    // Return subTotal function that totals the initial cost for all
    var subTotal = Sub(milk, fine, both, truff);
    document.getElementById('subtotal').textContent = subTotal;
    //Return Tax function totals
    var salesTax = Tax(subTotal);
    document.getElementById('tax').textContent = salesTax;
    // Return the total cost for Subtotal cost and salesTax cost
    var Total = displayTotal(subTotal, salesTax);
    document.getElementById('total').textContent = Total;
    // Display discount pricing
    var DiscountTotal = Total * .15;
    document.getElementById('final').textContent = DiscountTotal;
}

//Returns an array of error messages
function checkErrors() {
var list = [];

for (var j = 1; j<4; j++){

if (document.getElementById('ch-' + j + '-qnt').value <0 ) {
    document.getElementById('errors').innerHTML = list;
    }   
}
return list;
}

// Display total item counts
function displayItems() {
var total = 0;
var input = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control items');
for (var i=0; i<input.length; i++){
    total += parseFloat(input[i].value);
}
document.getElementById('nitems').textContent = total;  
}

//Function to return the subtotal for all 4 inputs
function Sub(milk, fine, both, truff) {
var total1, total2, total3, total4 = 0;
var Final = 0;
var costMilk = 7.48;
var costFine = 9.98;
var costBoth = 12.98;
var costTruff = 15.98;

total1 = costMilk * milk;
total2 = costFine *fine;
total3 = costBoth * both;
total4 = costTruff * truff;

Final = total1 + total2 + total3 + total4;
return Final;
}

// Returns tax total
function Tax(subTotal) {

subTotal = Sub(milk, fine, both, truff);
var Tax = subTotal * .05;

return Tax;
}

function displayTotal(Tax, Sub){

return Tax * Sub;

}

};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Include jQuery library -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  thead { background-color: #333; color: #fff; font-weight: bold;  }
  .items, #nitems, #subtotal, #tax, #total, #final {text-align: right; width: 100px; }
  #checkout { margin-bottom: 45px; width: 200px; height: 50px; font-weight: bold; }
  #errors { padding-bottom: 200px; clear: both; font-weight: bold; clear: both; font-size: 20px;
  color: blue;
 }
</style>

</head>
<body class='container'>
<form name="testForm">
  <div class='row'>
  <div class='col-md-8'>
   <h2>Sam's Online Shop</h2>

   <h3>15% discount on all online sales </h3>

   <h3>Our World Famous Chocolates Now Available Online </h3>
     <table class='table'>
     <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Product</th><th>Unit cost</th><th>Quantity</th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td id="ch-1-label">Milk Chocolate</td>
      <td id="ch-1-cost">7.48</td>
      <td><input size=3 name="milkchoc" id="ch-1-qnt" class="form-control items" value="0"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td id="ch-2-label">Assorted Fine Chocolates</td>
      <td id="ch-2-cost">9.98</td>
      <td><input size=3 name="foil" id="ch-2-qnt" class="form-control items" value="0"></td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
      <td id="ch-3-label">Assorted Milk & Dark Chocolates</td>
      <td id="ch-3-cost">12.98</td>
      <td><input size=3 name="dc" id="ch-3-qnt" class="form-control items" value="0"></td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
      <td id="ch-4-label">Assorted Dessert Truffles</td>
      <td id="ch-4-cost">15.98</td>
      <td><input size=3 name="dt" id="ch-4-qnt" class="form-control items" value="0"></td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class='row'>
   <div class='col-md-4'>

  <h3>Shopping Cart </h3>
  <table class='table'>
    <tr>
      <td>Total Items</td>
      <td><span  id="nitems" >0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Subtotal</td>
      <td><span  id="subtotal" >0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5% Sales tax</td>
      <td><span id="tax" >0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td><span id="total" >0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Final amount (with 15% discount)</td>
      <td><span id="final"  >0</td>
    </tr>
   </table>



 <p><input type="button" value="Purchase" id="checkout" class="form-control btn btn-primary" /></p>
 <p><span id='errors'></span></p>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Ok thank you very much for pointing those out. I am really pleased however that most of my coding was correct. At least the process of connecting my functions :)